# Datascraping using Beautiful soup. Finding the wrong body

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learning to web scrape. When I do ctrl + U to see the source code I don't see any of the data I want to however if I inspect the page i can find the information in a different body.

I have written the following code:

```
url = "https://hereford.ttleagues.com/rankings/24018e59-6861-4082-bb62-5455224a3ad8"

result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
table1 = doc.find("body")
```

I find a body but not the one I am looking for.
[The body I want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQCFN.png)

[The Body I find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noPh1.png)

Is anybody able to tell me how to find the first body the has the information i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that's in the body you want comes from an API and is dynamically rendered.

You can query the API endpoint and rebuild the table.

For example:

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    "Host": "ttleagues-api.azurewebsites.net",
    "Referer": "https://hereford.ttleagues.com/",
    "Tenant": "hereford.ttleagues.com",
}

player_id = "24018e59-6861-4082-bb62-5455224a3ad8"
url = f"https://ttleagues-api.azurewebsites.net/api/rankings/{player_id}/stats"

results = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["results"]

stats = []
for result in results:
    stats.append(
        [
            result["opponent"]["value"],
            result["versus"]["value"],
            datetime.datetime
            .strptime(result["date"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            .strftime("%d %b %Y"),
            result["for"],
            result["against"],
            " ".join(f"{g['for']}:{g['against']}" for g in result["games"]),
        ]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    stats,
    columns=["Opponent", "Versus", "Date", "For", "Against", "Game Scores"],
)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
```

Output:

```
+------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------+
| Opponent               | Versus        | Date        |   For |   Against | Game Scores                 |
|------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------|
| Trevor Davies          | Beekeepers    | 08 Nov 2022 |     3 |         0 | 15:13 11:1 11:8             |
| Lincoln Franklin       | Beekeepers    | 08 Nov 2022 |     3 |         2 | 8:11 12:10 11:6 9:11 11:9   |
| Stephen Brown          | Beekeepers    | 08 Nov 2022 |     2 |         3 | 3:11 11:4 9:11 12:10 14:16  |
| Andrew Reece           | Panthers      | 25 Oct 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:1 11:6 11:7              |
| Mark Playle            | Panthers      | 25 Oct 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:6 11:8 11:5              |
| Harmesh Jutle          | Panthers      | 25 Oct 2022 |     3 |         1 | 11:4 8:11 11:2 11:9         |
| Paul Oatley            | Warriors      | 19 Oct 2022 |     3 |         1 | 11:5 11:8 7:11 11:8         |
| Toby Eckley            | Warriors      | 19 Oct 2022 |     0 |         3 | 9:11 8:11 7:11              |
| Ola Andersson          | Warriors      | 19 Oct 2022 |     1 |         3 | 5:11 3:11 12:10 7:11        |
| Andy Castle            | Dodgers       | 11 Oct 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:8 11:7 11:6              |
| Alan Smith             | Dodgers       | 11 Oct 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:8 11:4 11:8              |
| Sam Turner             | Dodgers       | 11 Oct 2022 |     3 |         2 | 12:14 11:9 14:12 13:15 11:8 |
| Patryk Kowacz          | Pioneers      | 06 Oct 2022 |     0 |         3 | 10:12 7:11 7:11             |
| Julian Clapp           | Pioneers      | 06 Oct 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:5 11:5 11:4              |
| Piotr Sniezek          | Pioneers      | 06 Oct 2022 |     0 |         3 | 10:12 10:12 7:11            |
| Zak Weaver             | Outcasts      | 27 Sep 2022 |     3 |         2 | 7:11 11:9 9:11 11:6 11:7    |
| Dylan Day              | Outcasts      | 27 Sep 2022 |     2 |         3 | 11:5 10:12 10:12 11:4 10:12 |
| Simon Morgan           | Outcasts      | 27 Sep 2022 |     2 |         3 | 11:9 9:11 3:11 11:9 10:12   |
| Stephen Brown          | Beekeepers    | 22 Sep 2022 |     2 |         3 | 11:9 8:11 12:10 8:11 8:11   |
| Trevor Davies          | Beekeepers    | 22 Sep 2022 |     1 |         3 | 8:11 9:11 11:6 6:11         |
| Lincoln Franklin       | Beekeepers    | 22 Sep 2022 |     1 |         3 | 13:11 9:11 7:11 12:14       |
| Huan Davies            | Commitments   | 03 Mar 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:4 11:7 11:5              |
| Brian Caldicutt        | Commitments   | 03 Mar 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:4 11:7 11:5              |
| Andrew Reece           | Commitments   | 03 Mar 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:4 12:10 11:5             |
| Patryk Kowacz          | Welly Wangers | 22 Feb 2022 |     2 |         3 | 8:11 13:15 11:6 11:9 5:11   |
| Nigel Foreshew         | Welly Wangers | 22 Feb 2022 |     1 |         3 | 5:11 11:5 7:11 7:11         |
| Ken Read               | Welly Wangers | 22 Feb 2022 |     0 |         3 | 9:11 8:11 8:11              |
| Radoslaw Mikolajczyk   | Pioneers      | 15 Feb 2022 |     1 |         3 | 11:7 7:11 8:11 5:11         |
| Yan Liu                | Pioneers      | 15 Feb 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:3 11:3 11:9              |
| Harmesh Jutle          | Pioneers      | 15 Feb 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:6 11:4 11:6              |
| Rod Davies             | Magpies       | 02 Feb 2022 |     1 |         3 | 11:7 9:11 7:11 7:11         |
| Toby Eckley            | Magpies       | 02 Feb 2022 |     2 |         3 | 12:10 4:11 11:3 6:11 7:11   |
| Paul Oatley            | Magpies       | 02 Feb 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:5 11:7 11:8              |
| Waldemar Kogut         | Panthers      | 25 Jan 2022 |     1 |         3 | 11:9 8:11 9:11 8:11         |
| Pratikcha Chamling Rai | Panthers      | 25 Jan 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:1 13:11 11:6             |
| Harmesh Jutle          | Panthers      | 25 Jan 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:7 11:7 11:8              |
| Ian Godding            | Badgers       | 19 Jan 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:4 11:8 11:9              |
| Mark Conod             | Badgers       | 19 Jan 2022 |     3 |         1 | 11:2 13:11 8:11 12:10       |
| Jake Conod             | Badgers       | 19 Jan 2022 |     3 |         1 | 11:8 7:11 11:7 12:10        |
| Alan Smith             | Dodgers       | 11 Jan 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:2 11:9 12:10             |
| Andy Castle            | Dodgers       | 11 Jan 2022 |     1 |         3 | 12:10 8:11 5:11 5:11        |
| Bryan Farr             | Dodgers       | 11 Jan 2022 |     3 |         0 | 11:9 11:8 11:6              |
| Dylan Day              | Outcasts      | 13 Dec 2021 |     1 |         3 | 11:9 3:11 7:11 13:15        |
| Zak Weaver             | Outcasts      | 13 Dec 2021 |     0 |         3 | 2:11 7:11 10:12             |
| Simon Morgan           | Outcasts      | 13 Dec 2021 |     2 |         3 | 8:11 5:11 11:6 14:12 1:11   |
| Bob Marshall           | Commitments   | 30 Nov 2021 |     3 |         0 | 11:8 11:7 11:4              |
| Pratikcha Chamling Rai | Commitments   | 30 Nov 2021 |     3 |         0 | 11:2 11:5 11:8              |
| Brian Caldicutt        | Commitments   | 30 Nov 2021 |     3 |         0 | 11:4 11:7 11:4              |
| Toby Eckley            | Magpies       | 02 Nov 2021 |     2 |         3 | 11:6 11:13 14:12 15:17 8:11 |
| Chris Martin           | Magpies       | 02 Nov 2021 |     1 |         3 | 7:11 11:8 6:11 8:11         |
+------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much @baduker , that was really helpful! If it wasn't too much trouble please could you help me extract the game scores as well. I have been trying since you helped previously but am getting nowhere. this is what i tried within the for loop you made:

        for game in result["games"]:
        stats.append(
            [
            game["for"]["value"],
            game["against"]["value"],
            ]
        )

Comment: Thanks again @baduker. Trying to understand your code to be able to adapt it to other situations. Could you please explain why you added "/stats" to the end of the url

Comment: I don't add it. It's there as a part of the endpoint URL. I only modify the player id.